# is it possible to create scripts in Netezza like SQL server?

Tags: netezza

I am trying to create the script in netezza like what we do in SQL server with variable declaration but I am not able to do it.

Need to create a temp table and then need to pass the parameter to it through a variable.

```
DECLARE var1 varchar(10);
```

through error message every time

How to drop a temp table. and how the temp table data is stored and cleared in the memory?

Comment: please also post the error message you are getting..

Comment: Error Message ERROR:  'DECLARE var1 varchar(10)'
error    ^ found "DECLARE" (at char 1) expecting a keyword

Comment: not sure - but try using `DECLARE var1 VARCHAR(10);` - meaning use uppercase `VARCHAR` instead of `varchar`. I don't know any Sql sorry :) Someone else will help you if this is not the problem. :)

Comment: Thank you Alon, But getting the same error. I think there is not much people working in Netezza.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netezza has its own language for stored procedures - same concept as SQLserver but closer to oracle syntax.
It is however not possible to use the 'variables' construct outside such a stored procedure, which leaves you with a couple of options in your case:
 1. do a 'create or replace procedure' with your script embedded, and the execute the sp 
 2. store intermediate results in temporary tables, and do the 'if-then-else' logic in another scripting language (perl powershell or the like)

We went for option 1 in most cases when moving from SQLserver to Netezza about a year ago...